# What is the technique behind chords progression

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

Why does the key of C have chords like C major, D minor, etc? What is the reason that the D Minor chord is part of C? What are the fundamentals of building chord progression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of C major has the following notes: **C D E F G A B**

If you take any note of the above and build a chord (which are build on thirds), you get the following chords:

- C major: C E G
- D minor: D F A
- E minor: E G B
- F major: F A C
- G major: G B D
- A minor: A C E
- B diminished: B D F